# How can I resolve the IP address and then set a variable to the resolved pc name

Tags: variables, batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to think of an easier way, read less prone to messing up the commands, to resolve an IP address and then set a variable to said resolved name.  I tried the following:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=3 DELIMS=gw" %%A IN ('PING -a -n 1 IPADDRESS') DO SET "PC=%%A"
```

Which on:

```
Pinging PCNAME [IPADDRESS} with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from IPADDRESS: bytes=32 time =15ms TTL=122

Ping statistics for IPADDRESS:
   Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
   Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 15ms, Average = 15ms
```

Works for most pc names.  There are only a few "g" and "w" so the only line with a 3rd token is the first. The problem I experienced is that we have A LOT of pc names and a few have a "g" in them.  For those resolved addresses it cuts of the variable at the 3rd "g" of the line.

I tried using it on NSLOOKUP, but the command gives me:

```
C:\Windows\System32>nslookup IPADDRESS
Server:  SERVERNAME
Address:  SERVERIP

Name:    PCNAME
Address:  IPADDRESS
```

I can skip in FOR /F (ie skip 2) but then the it reads lines 3 AND 4; ie it sets the variable to the pc name for line 3, but then changes it on line 4 to garbage I don't need.

Like I said is there a way to this easily?  I can do a for in a for with calls and delayed expansion, but that is much harder to keep track of.

Comment: Gosh - use Powershell.  Or VBscript.  *Anything* but a .bat file!!!!

Comment: @FoggyDay It's more of a `.cmd` file already.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the info you need ("Name:")

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%i in ('nslookup 192.168.178.1^|find "Name:"') do set name=%%i
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using. Funny because I was editing an older script when I came across this and it just hit me like a brick wall.

Comment: Nice +1, I had the same question but the other way around, I need the IP address. This worked perfectly too (doing do set Address=%%i  at the end instead. It just happens that the ones I'm looking up don't have multiple ips so it works fine    // obviously I don't use the find name part)

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple method that may be used with both PING or NSLOOKUP.

With PING:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2" %%A IN ('PING -a -n 1 IPADDRESS') DO SET "PC=%%A" & GOTO CONTINUE
:CONTINUE
```

With NSLOOKUP:

```
FOR /F "SKIP=2 TOKENS=2" %%A in ('NSLOOKUP IPADDRESS') DO SET "PC=%%A" & GOTO CONTINUE
:CONTINUE
```

The GOTO CONTINUE is used to break the FOR after the desired information was taken.

Comment: ....I do have to express my most sincere gratitude for the "& GOTO CONTINUE" part.  SKIP well skips a few lines, but then reads all others, with that I can select just the line I want. Beautiful. Thank you. Helps me with a few other things.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions

    set "ip=127.0.0.1"
    set "pcName="

    for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -a %ip% 2^>nul') do if not defined pcName if not "%%c"=="" (
        set "pcName=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%d in ("!pcName: =\!.") do ( endlocal & set "pcName=%%~nxd")
    )

    echo %pcName%
```

This reads the output of ping command, and splits the lines using `[]`. The only line containing square brackets is the line with the pc name (if found). We will skip lines that are not splitted in three tokens (`%%c` is empty).

The first token will contain the pc name prefixed by a string indicating a ping operation is being done. This string is localized and changes depending of the windows language (in my case, spanish windows, it is *"Haciendo ping a"*). So, asking for a fixed token is not reliable. To avoid it, the string is converted to a false path by replacing the spaces with backslashes. Then the standard `for` replaceable parameter modifiers are used to retrieve the name of the last element in the false path, that is, the pc name.

Answer (score 0):

Using the original approach:

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=2* DELIMS=gw" %%A IN ('PING -a -n 1 IPADDRESS') DO if not "%%B"=="" for /f %%C in ("%%B") do SET "PC=%%C"
```

(just to demo)